# How to handle adding ignored files to new branch and switching back to old branch

Tags: git

I am adding "new-directory" to a new branch. It contains the "my-code" directory with stuff that I need to check into git, and a "generated-files" directory with many generated files that I do not want to check in.

I am therefore adding a .gitignore file, that makes sure that "generated files" will be ignored.

```
\new-directory
   .gitignore
   \my-code
   \generated-files
```

I add three code files to "my-code", start the program which generates 1000 files in "generated-files". I look at my changes: three changes, perfect, I check in and switch to an older branch to fix a bug.

In the old branch the 1000 generated files appear as new files.

How do I properly get rid of these?

Ideas I have right now:

1. Delete the new files whenever I switch to an old branch that does not contain the .gitignore in "new-directory".
2. Stage desired changes to the old branch and only commit those.
3. Add \new-directory\.gitignore to the old branch. (The downside is that there are two different commits with the same change. When (if?) the two branches eventually are merged, then there will certainly be merge conflicts. Also, having a directory with only a .gitignore file seems a little strange)
4. Check out the new branch into a separate repository.

But none of these are great; each has downsides.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: The two branches can be rebased to help prevent the first issue, and the second can be done by commenting inside the .gitignore file.
I think it overall depends on the end goal, if this new-directory should eventually end up in the project then the .gitignore will get there eventually.

I've also just remembered another option: .git/info/exclude which is your machine local git ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a post-checkout githook that deletes the offending folder when the current branch (that you just checked out) is not the one associated with the generated files

Comment: This is interesting and something I did not know about. I have to try this.